# Websocket client not connecting to

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

Everything is running smoothly in the back end.

However when I try to establish the connection to the front with google chrome, I get the following error message.

```
 WebSocket connection to 'wss://127.0.0.1:5000/' failed: create-a-chart
```

I can not solve this, I don't know if it is a problem with the server, a problem withe browser, or something else. I tested it with Firefox and it did not work neither.

I am using express server + websocket server + ejs (it powers the vue).

In the ejs.js file, in the layout.ejs:

```
<html>
...
<script defer src="/js/index.js"></script>

<script>

//Used the following paths and it did not work:

//const socket =  new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:5000/create-a-chart");
//const socket =  new WebSocket("wss://localhost/create-a-chart");
//const socket =  new WebSocket("wss://localhost/");

// Create WebSocket connection.

const socket =  new WebSocket("wss://127.0.0.1:5000/");
console.log(location.host)

// Connection opened

socket.addEventListener('open', function (event) {
     console.log('Connected to WS Server')
    });
</script>

</html>
```

In the app.js file I get:

```
const express = require("express");
const expressLayouts = require("express-ejs-layouts");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const passport = require("passport");
const flash = require("connect-flash");
const session = require("express-session");
const path = require("path");
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');

////For ws
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });

app.use(cors({origin: '*'}));
// Passport Config
require("./config/passport")(passport);

// DB Config
const db = require("./config/keys").mongoURI;

// Connect to MongoDB
mongoose
  .connect(db, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then(() => console.log("MongoDB Connected"))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));

// EJS
app.use(expressLayouts);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

// Express body parser
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// Express session
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "secret",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
  })
);

// Passport middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Connect flash
app.use(flash());


// Global variables
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.success_msg = req.flash("success_msg");
  res.locals.error_msg = req.flash("error_msg");
  res.locals.error = req.flash("error");
  next();
});

// Routes
app.use("/", require("./routes/index.js"));
app.use("/users", require("./routes/users.js"));


/////Connection to socket.io
wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
   ws.send('Welcome New Client!');
  console.log('A new client Connected!');
})


//Server (app an ws) listen to port
server.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, () => {
    console.log(`Server started on port ${server.address().port} :)`);
});
```

Comment: Are you actually using [socket.io](https://socket.io/docs/v4/)? It doesn't seem to be required in posted code. AFAIK socket.io automatically upgrades its connection protocol to WS from HTTP iff the server supports the HTTP upgrade request.

Comment: I used socket.io and I had the same issue. And then I switched to websocket. I had the same result :/

Comment: you use `wss://` as protocol on the client, but your server ist not sercured. Try `ws://` The "create-a-chart" part is a bit strage, but the wss/ws error is the most obvious one.

Comment: I already tried that. I changed wss to ws did not work. If I ever find I ll put the answer.